# What type hint to use for parameter in parent class for child class?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, type-hinting

I have a strange situation where I'm unclear on what type hint I can use to essentially say `any child class`.  In this example, I have a shared algorithm I don't want to duplicate across all the children class, that requires knowledge about the base class only.

```
import abc


class Animal(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, line: str) -> None:
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def is_alive(self) -> bool:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def eat(cls: WHATGOESHERE) -> None:
        """Do the same thing for any child class."""
        if cls.is_alive():
            print("Put food in mouth hole.")


class Human(Animal):

    def __init__(self, line: str) -> None:
        self.heart_beating = bool(line[-1])

    def is_alive(self) -> bool:
        return self.heart_beating

  ...


class Jellyfish(Animal):
  
    def __init__(self, line: str) -> None:
        self.wiggling = bool(line[-1])

    def is_alive(self) -> bool:
        return self.wiggling

    ...
```

What type can I use for `WHATGOESHERE`?

Comment: Animal? Any child *is an* animal.

Comment: That unfortunately fails my linter.  `Type[TypeVar('ConcreteAnimal', bound='Animal')]` appears to work but I can't explain it.